# In TabView, disable tabs but enable dynamic content

Tags: dynamic

Is it possible to have a TabView where the tabs are disabled but the dynamic contents are still responsive?

In the following, all dynamic content seems to be disabled. I would like the Manipulate to remain active but the tabs not clickable.

```
TabView[{Manipulate[x, {x, 1, 10}], 2}, Enabled -> False]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so without additional info, here's what you can use:

```
TabView[{Manipulate[x, {x, 1, 10}], 2}, Dynamic[1, None]]
```

`TabView` second argument determines the active tab but `None` action for `Dynamic` prevents from changing it.

Comment: This is perfect. I didn't realize the second argument of Dynamic could be used this way... this is what I was looking to do: `DynamicModule[{tab = 1}, Column[{TabView[{1 -> Button["Go to tab 2", tab = 2], Style[2, Gray] -> 2, 3 -> 3}, Dynamic[tab, If[# == 2, None, tab = #] &]]}]]`